# Finding the trace of a block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, block-matrices

> Let $A$ be a $5 \times 5$ skew-symmetric matrix with entries in $\mathbb{R}$ and $B$ be the $5 \times 5$ symmetric matrix whose $(i, j)^{th}$ entry is the binomial coefficient $\binom{i}{j}$ for $1 \le i \le j \le 5$. Consider the $10 \times 10$ matrix, given in block form by $$ C = \left (
> \begin{matrix}
>   A & A+B \\
>   0 & B  
>  \end{matrix} \right ).$$ Then show that trace of $C$ is $5$.

I came across the above problem. I see that $\text{trace} C = \text{trace} A + \text{trace} B$. Now we see that $\text{trace}B=1+1+1+1+1=5$ (by the given condition, since $\binom{i}{i}=1$). Now the only thing that remains to prove that $\text{trace}A=0$. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The only thing that remains to be observed is that the diagonal of a skew-symmetric matrix is made of $0$'s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $A$ is skew-symmetric, $a_{i,i}=-a_{i,i}$ so $a_{i,i}=0$.
Hence $Tr\;A=0$.

Now you have seen that $Tr\;B=5$.

So $Tr\;C=Tr\;A+Tr\;B=0+5=5$.

Answer (score 0):

In a skew-symmetric matrix the diagonal entries are zero implying the trace is zero.